# Remove First and last line of File using Pig Script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I want to remove the first and last line/row of my file in HDFS using pig script. I tried to achieve this using **Rank** and it worked but i should know the last rank number to remove it but my file is dynamic it can have more or less rows, for that case i am not able to find anything. Please help

**EDIT:**
My data is huge so i cannot create schema and cannot group them to use **MIN()** how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have Rank available, you can get the first and last rank which you want to exclude (i.e. first and last line of you file) by mean of MIN and MAX eval functions. This way you need not to hard code the rank filter.

1. [Eval function MAX](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/func.html#max)
2. [Eval function MIN](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/func.html#min)

Note: this is for pig version 0.16.0.

Comment: is there anyother way to achieve this ?

Comment: my data is huge i cannot create schema and group them. In that case Min is not working for me.

Comment: Warning, this will remove the first or last line of your load. If you use load to load in a directory with multiple files you will need more complicated tricks to get the desired result!